# 404 Resource not found when running Apache Fineract for local Development

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, apache-fineract

Im trying to set up [fineract](https://github.com/apache/fineract) for local development in windows 11 (with java 17)

Im running the docker image for maria db

```
         docker run --name mariadb-10.9 -p 3306:3306 -e MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql -d mariadb:10.9
```

Then I ran these scripts to set up the DB

```
        ./gradlew createDB -PdbName=fineract_tenants
        ./gradlew createDB -PdbName=fineract_default
```

Now if I either run

```
   ./gradlew bootRun
```

OR start the **ServerApplication** usig inteliJ, the application starts and I'm able to access the swagger via

> http://localhost:8443/fineract-provider/swagger-ui/index.html#/

Im also getting  "status": "UP" for

> http://localhost:8443/fineract-provider/actuator/health

However when I try to invoke an API resource Im getting a 404 Error.

e.g

GET http://localhost:8443/fineract-provider/api/v1/v1/glclosures?officeId=123

Gives

> {
> "timestamp": "2024-01-02T02:09:29.697Z",
> "status": 404,
> "error": "Not Found",
> "path": "/fineract-provider/api/v1/v1/glclosures"
> }

This is happening for all resources at /fineract-provider/*

I think eventhough the application is running the API resources are not deployed properly. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the extra /v1 in the API URL does the trick